# How to use like when using 2 persons in a sentence?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

Which of these is it:

> Robert and Mike like their presents.
>   Robert and Mike likes their presents.

Comment: I would like to use the verb 'like' in this sentence, but not sure how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

There are two nouns in your sentence, therefore, following the 3th person's rule, which results in not adding any "*S*" in sentences that contain two or more nouns, no "*S*" must be added, since two nouns have been mentioned.

> Davyd and Jay like their presents
>
> Davyd likes his present - 3th person's rule.

Some extra details: This works to any verb, like, do, eat, make, touch....

Here are others examples:

> Jay eats in this restaurant everyday
>
> Jay and I eat in this restaurant everyday
>
> Jay and Davyd make their own presents.
>
> Davyd makes his own present.

Comment: In general, it's better to answer the original question, not the duplicate.

Comment: The other question was poste 3 years ago and has been answered already, I also added some completements to the answer in order to make it more clear

Comment: @Davyd Diniz Thank you for your answers. I always get confuse whether to add an -s when using two singular nouns in a sentence.

Comment: @Davyd - I understand, but it's still better to answer the duplicate, if you think more can be or should be added. Otherwise, as more duplicates get asked, you have to go to more and more questions to find the complete answer.